# Combine the values of two hash keys in an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
a = [{"ID"=>"FOO", "Type"=>"Name"}, {"ID"=>"1234", "Type"=>"CID"}]
```

I'm trying to extract the hash where the `Type=='CID'`, then combine the two values to result in `CID=1234`.

I can do this in multiple steps:

```
h = a.find{|x| x['Type']=='CID'}
# => {"ID"=>"1234", "Type"=>"CID"}

"#{h['Type']}=#{h['ID']}"
# => "CID=1234"
```

Is there a way to do this in a one liner?

Comment: I think I’m missing something - where does 9502 come from

Comment: What are "the two values"?

Comment: I made a correction.  The two values are `1234` and `CID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one line using:

```rb
a.select{|x| x['Type']=='CID'}
  .map{|x| "type=#{x['Type']},id=#{x['ID']}"}[0]
```

Comment: Just in case, it works also with `[{"ID"=>"FOO", "Type"=>"Name"}, {"ID"=>"1234", "Type"=>"CID"}, {"ID"=>"5678", "Type"=>"CID"}]`, removing `.[0]`, it returns the array of strings.

Answer (score 4):

```
a.find { |h| h["Type"] == "CID" }&.values_at("Type", "ID")&.join("=")
  #=>"CID=1234"

a.find { |h| h["Type"] == "cat" }&.values_at("Type", "ID")&.join("=")
  #=> nil
```

`&` is Ruby's [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/), which made it's debut in Ruby v2.3. I added it to cause `nil` to be returned if there is no match on `h["Type"]`.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

if we are not having multiple values of Type = "CID":

```
   a.select{|x| x["Type"] == "CID"}.map{|x| x.values_at("Type", "ID")}.join("=")
```

if we have are having Type="CID"

```
a.detect{|x| x["Type"]=="CID"}.values_at("Type", "ID").join("=")
```

If we don't have Type="CID" in above array will throw an error, be cautious.

Need to work in all cases we need to do:

```
 a.detect{|x| x["Type"]=="CID"}.values_at("Type", "ID").join("=") if a.detect{|x| x["Type"]=="CID"}
```

Comment: You are depending on the key-value pairs being in a particular order.

Comment: @GaganGami Thank you, I have fixed the syntax issue

Comment: `detect` returns `nil` in case of no match, then `nil.values` returns an error.  What if the order in the hash is reversed, `{"Type"=>"CID", "ID"=>"5678"}`? To fix the syntax need to remove the closed square bracket.